# Why is Jupyter Notebook failing to load JavaScript (thinking, I am using JupyterLab)?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipython, ipywidgets

#### What I'm trying to do

I'm writing a Python (version==3.8.X) script for interactive visualization of molecules, which is working perfectly fine in VS Code but not in classical Jupyter Notebooks anymore (it did though just 2 weeks ago). For its practical use case with my employer it needs to be able to be run in Jupyter Notebook but it seems impossible for me to set Jupyter up the correct way on my personal machine (Arch Linux) as well as work stations at work (Ubuntu Linux) even though I've had both running fine lately.

#### Information I've collected

1. These are two screenshots of the outputs of the exact same cell (same file), when using [Jupyter Notebook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mbSWcvy_c-yeBUjA2IK41078Ra6a1HAc/view?usp=share_link) and here in [VS Code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gnSZfa3GTentWguPQc0E1SMUOUQKQ0F8/view?usp=share_link).
2. Output of `jupyter nbextension list`:

   ```
   Known nbextensions:
     config dir: /home/lnrd/.jupyter/nbconfig
       notebook section
         nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main  enabled 
         - Validating: problems found:
           - require?  X nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main
         contrib_nbextensions_help_item/main  enabled 
         - Validating: OK
         jupyter-js-widgets/extension  enabled 
         - Validating: OK
         jupyterlab disabled
       tree  section
         nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main  enabled 
         - Validating: problems found:
           - require?  X nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main
     config dir: /home/lnrd/.local/etc/jupyter/nbconfig
       notebook section
         ipyevents/extension  enabled 
         - Validating: OK
         nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main  enabled 
         - Validating: problems found:
           - require?  X nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main
         jupyter-js-widgets/extension  enabled 
         - Validating: OK
       tree section
         nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main  enabled 
         - Validating: problems found:
           - require?  X nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main
     config dir: /etc/jupyter/nbconfig
       notebook section
         jupyter-js-widgets/extension  enabled 
         - Validating: OK
   ```
3. Output of `jupyter troubleshoot`. I'm unsure about the meaning of the `sys.<var>` paths and where those are configured. I do understand `$PATH`, how it's configured and what it means for software in my OS. I guess `pip list` here is equal to `py310 -m pip list`.

   - I'm guessing the `sys.<var>` references the python kernel which Jupyter is running
   - I unsuccessfully tried setting up and using my py38 install as kernel (`sys.version` within the notebook then gave me `3.8.X`) but errors had been the same

     - even with py38 as kernel, `jupyter notebook --debug` output (see below) had been looking for files in py310 directories. Maybe I've just made a mistake setting up the py38 kernel correctly but maybe not.
     - when using `jupyter nbextension enable` sometimes I've used the `--py` and `--user` flags and sometimes didn't - could this have been an issue?

   ```
   $PATH:
    /home/lnrd/bin
    /usr/local/sbin
    /usr/local/bin
    /usr/sbin
    /usr/bin
    /sbin
    /bin
    /usr/games
    /usr/local/games
    /usr/bin/site_perl
    /usr/bin/vendor_perl
    /usr/bin/core_perl
    /home/lnrd/.local/bin

   sys.path:
    /usr/bin
    /usr/lib/python310.zip
    /usr/lib/python3.10
    /usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload
    /home/lnrd/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
    /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages

   sys.executable:
    /usr/bin/python

   sys.version:
    3.10.9 (main, Dec 19 2022, 17:35:49) [GCC 12.2.0]

   platform.platform():
    Linux-6.1.8-arch1-1-x86_64-with-glibc2.36

   which -a jupyter:
    /usr/sbin/jupyter
    /usr/bin/jupyter
    /sbin/jupyter
    /bin/jupyter
    /home/lnrd/.local/bin/jupyter

   pip list:
    Package                           Version
    --------------------------------- -----------
    aiohttp                           3.7.4.post0
    aiohttp-retry                     2.8.3
    alabaster                         0.7.13
    amqp                              5.1.1
    antlr4-python3-runtime            4.9.3
    anyio                             3.6.2
    anytree                           2.8.0
    appdirs                           1.4.4
    apptools                          5.2.0
    argon2-cffi                       21.3.0
    argon2-cffi-bindings              21.2.0
    arrow                             1.2.3
    ase                               3.22.1
    astroid                           2.13.3
    asttokens                         2.2.1
    async-generator                   1.10
    async-timeout                     3.0.1
    asyncssh                          2.12.0
    atpublic                          3.1.1
    attrs                             22.2.0
    autocommand                       2.2.2
    autopep8                          1.6.0
    Babel                             2.11.0
    backcall                          0.2.0
    beautifulsoup4                    4.11.1
    billiard                          3.6.4.0
    bleach                            6.0.0
    breezy                            3.3.2
    Brlapi                            0.8.4
    btrfsutil                         6.1.3
    CacheControl                      0.12.11
    celery                            5.2.7
    certifi                           2022.12.7
    cffi                              1.15.1
    chardet                           4.0.0
    click                             8.1.3
    click-didyoumean                  0.3.0
    click-plugins                     1.1.1
    click-repl                        0.2.0
    colorama                          0.4.6
    comm                              0.1.2
    commonmark                        0.9.1
    configobj                         5.1.0.dev0
    contextlib2                       21.6.0
    cryptography                      39.0.0
    cssselect                         1.2.0
    cycler                            0.11.0
    Cython                            0.29.33
    debugpy                           1.6.6
    decorator                         5.1.1
    defusedxml                        0.7.1
    deprecation                       2.1.0
    dictdiffer                        0.9.0
    dill                              0.3.6
    discord                           1.7.3
    discord.py                        1.7.3
    diskcache                         5.4.0
    distlib                           0.3.6
    distro                            1.8.0
    dnspython                         2.2.1
    docutils                          0.19
    dpath                             2.0.6
    dscribe                           1.2.2
    dulwich                           0.20.46
    dvc-data                          0.8.0
    dvc-http                          2.19.1
    dvc-objects                       0.2.2
    dvc-render                        0.0.10
    dvc-task                          0.1.2
    dvclive                           0.10.0
    entrypoints                       0.4
    envisage                          6.1.0
    evdev                             1.6.1
    executing                         1.2.0
    fastbencode                       0.1
    fastjsonschema                    2.16.2
    flake8                            4.0.1
    flatten-dict                      0.4.2
    flufl.lock                        7.1.1
    fonttools                         4.29.1
    fqdn                              1.5.1
    fsspec                            2022.8.2
    funcy                             1.17
    future                            0.18.2
    gitdb                             4.0.9
    GitPython                         3.1.27
    grandalf                          0.6
    greenlet                          1.1.2
    html5lib                          1.1
    hydra-core                        1.2.0
    idna                              3.4
    imagesize                         1.4.1
    importlib-metadata                5.0.0
    inflect                           6.0.2
    ipyevents                         2.0.1
    ipykernel                         6.20.2
    ipython                           8.9.0
    ipython-genutils                  0.2.0
    ipywidgets                        8.0.4
    isoduration                       20.11.0
    isort                             5.11.4
    jaraco.context                    4.2.0
    jaraco.functools                  3.5.2
    jaraco.text                       3.11.0
    jedi                              0.18.2
    Jinja2                            3.1.2
    joblib                            1.2.0
    json5                             0.9.12
    jsonpointer                       2.3
    jsonschema                        4.17.3
    jupyter                           1.0.0
    jupyter_client                    8.0.1
    jupyter-console                   6.4.4
    jupyter-contrib-core              0.4.2
    jupyter_core                      5.1.5
    jupyter-events                    0.6.3
    jupyter-nbextensions-configurator 0.6.1
    jupyter_packaging                 0.12.3
    jupyter-server                    1.23.5
    jupyter_server_terminals          0.4.4
    jupyterlab                        3.5.3
    jupyterlab-pygments               0.2.2
    jupyterlab_server                 2.19.0
    jupyterlab-widgets                3.0.5
    kiwisolver                        1.3.2
    kombu                             5.2.4
    lazy-object-proxy                 1.9.0
    ledfx                             0.10.7
    lensfun                           0.3.3
    libfdt                            1.6.1
    lit                               15.0.7.dev0
    llvmlite                          0.39.1
    louis                             3.24.0
    lxml                              4.9.2
    Markdown                          3.4.1
    markdown-it-py                    2.1.0
    MarkupSafe                        2.1.2
    matplotlib                        3.5.1
    matplotlib-inline                 0.1.6
    mayavi                            4.8.1
    mccabe                            0.6.1
    mdurl                             0.1.2
    merge3                            0.0.12
    meson                             1.0.0
    mistune                           2.0.4
    more-itertools                    9.0.0
    msgpack                           1.0.4
    multidict                         6.0.2
    mypy                              0.942
    mypy-extensions                   0.4.3
    nanotime                          0.5.2
    natsort                           8.1.0
    nbclassic                         0.5.1
    nbclient                          0.7.2
    nbconvert                         7.2.9
    nbformat                          5.7.3
    nest-asyncio                      1.5.6
    netsnmp-python                    1.0a1
    networkx                          2.8.6
    notebook                          6.5.2
    notebook_shim                     0.2.2
    nspektr                           0.4.0
    numba                             0.56.4
    numpy                             1.22.4
    omegaconf                         2.2.3
    ordered-set                       4.1.0
    packaging                         23.0
    pandas                            1.5.1
    pandocfilters                     1.5.0
    parso                             0.8.3
    pathspec                          0.9.0
    patiencediff                      0.2.12
    pep517                            0.13.0
    pexpect                           4.8.0
    pickleshare                       0.7.5
    Pillow                            9.4.0
    pip                               22.3.1
    platformdirs                      2.6.2
    pluggy                            1.0.0
    ply                               3.11
    progress                          1.6
    prometheus-client                 0.16.0
    prompt-toolkit                    3.0.36
    psutil                            5.9.4
    ptyprocess                        0.7.0
    pure-eval                         0.2.2
    pwquality                         1.4.5
    py3Dmol                           1.8.1
    PyAudio                           0.2.11
    pybind11                          2.10.1
    pycairo                           1.23.0
    pycodestyle                       2.10.0
    pycparser                         2.21
    pydantic                          1.10.4
    pydocstyle                        6.1.1
    pydot                             1.4.2
    pyface                            7.4.2
    pyflakes                          3.0.1
    pygit2                            1.10.1
    Pygments                          2.14.0
    PyGObject                         3.42.2
    pygtrie                           2.5.0
    pylint                            2.15.10
    pyls-isort                        0.2.2
    pylsp-mypy                        0.5.7
    PyNaCl                            1.5.0
    pynvim                            0.4.3
    pyOpenSSL                         23.0.0
    pyparsing                         3.0.9
    PyQt5                             5.15.6
    PyQt5-Qt5                         5.15.2
    PyQt5-sip                         12.9.1
    PyQt6                             6.4.1
    PyQt6-sip                         13.4.1
    pyqtgraph                         0.13.1
    pyrsistent                        0.19.3
    python-dateutil                   2.8.2
    python-dotenv                     0.20.0
    python-json-logger                2.0.4
    python-lsp-jsonrpc                1.0.0
    python-lsp-server                 1.4.1
    python-xlib                       0.31
    pytz                              2022.7
    pyxdg                             0.28
    PyYAML                            6.0
    pyzmq                             25.0.0
    qtconsole                         5.4.0
    QtPy                              2.3.0
    rdkit                             2022.9.3
    requests                          2.28.1
    requests-unixsocket               0.3.0
    resolvelib                        0.9.0
    retrying                          1.3.3
    rfc3339-validator                 0.1.4
    rfc3986-validator                 0.1.1
    rfc3987                           1.3.8
    rich                              13.3.1
    rope                              1.0.0
    ruamel.yaml                       0.17.21
    ruamel.yaml.clib                  0.2.6
    scikit-learn                      1.1.3
    scipy                             1.8.0
    scmrepo                           0.1.1
    Send2Trash                        1.8.0
    setproctitle                      1.3.2
    setuptools                        65.6.3
    shiboken6                         6.4.2
    shiboken6-generator               6.4.2
    shortuuid                         1.0.9
    shtab                             1.5.5
    simplejson                        3.18.0
    six                               1.16.0
    smmap                             5.0.0
    sniffio                           1.3.0
    snowballstemmer                   2.2.0
    soupsieve                         2.3.2.post1
    sparse                            0.13.0
    Sphinx                            5.3.0
    sphinxcontrib-applehelp           1.0.4
    sphinxcontrib-devhelp             1.0.2
    sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp            2.0.0
    sphinxcontrib-jsmath              1.0.1
    sphinxcontrib-qthelp              1.0.3
    sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml     1.1.5
    stack-data                        0.6.2
    tabulate                          0.8.10
    TBB                               0.2
    team                              1.0
    tenacity                          8.1.0
    terminado                         0.17.1
    terminator                        2.1.2
    testpath                          0.6.0
    threadpoolctl                     3.1.0
    tinycss2                          1.2.1
    toml                              0.10.2
    tomli                             2.0.1
    tomlkit                           0.11.6
    tornado                           6.2
    tqdm                              4.64.1
    traitlets                         5.8.1
    traits                            6.4.1
    traitsui                          7.4.2
    trove-classifiers                 2023.1.20
    typing_extensions                 4.4.0
    uc-micro-py                       1.0.1
    ujson                             5.2.0
    uri-template                      1.2.0
    urllib3                           1.26.12
    validate                          5.1.0.dev0
    validate-pyproject                0.12.1
    vimiv                             0.8.0
    vine                              5.0.0
    voluptuous                        0.13.1
    vtk                               9.2.2
    wcwidth                           0.2.6
    webcolors                         1.12
    webencodings                      0.5.1
    websocket-client                  1.5.0
    wheel                             0.38.4
    widgetsnbextension                4.0.5
    wrapt                             1.14.1
    wslink                            1.9.1
    wxPython                          4.2.0
    yapf                              0.32.0
    yarl                              1.7.2
    youtube-dl                        2021.12.17
    zc.lockfile                       2.0
    zipp                              3.12.0
   ```
4. Output of `jupyter notebook --debug` shows this one line containing status 404. I suspect this should lead me somewhere but I'm unsure what to do with this information:

   ```
   [W <time> NotebookApp] 404 GET /static/components/marked/lib/marked.js (127.0.0.1) 34.030000ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
   ```

#### What I've tried to fix this

1. gone through all config files in all `jupyter --paths` to check if `jupyter-js-widgets=true`
2. Used py38 and py310 kernels
3. with <py> as `py38=/usr/bin/python3.8` and `py310=/usr/bin/python3.10` i have

   - <py> -m pip install --upgrade jupyter notebook ipywidgets widgetsnbextension jupyter_contrib_nbextensions jupyter-js-widgets-nbextension
   - <py> -m pip install --force-reinstall jupyter notebook ipywidgets widgetsnbextension jupyter_contrib_nbextensions jupyter-js-widgets-nbextension
4. executing `jupyter contrib nbextension install`
5. disabling and enabling different jupyter nbextensions
6. JupyterLab

   - pip installing `JupyterLab`, enabling it and executing `jupyterlab extension install py3dmol` as suggested by error message from screenshot
   - uninstalling and disabling `JupyterLab` again because I hadn't used it when the code ran in Jupyter Notebook originally

Comment: For posting on StackOverflow, you don't want to bury things in images. The only place I see mention of py3dmol aside of your image is the very bottom of your post. Why not have it in the title? Instead of referring to general 'javascript'? Plus, you start out the text in your post talking about the classic Jupyter notebook interface yet at the very top in the title, you mention the JupyterLab interface and then at the bottom bring back up JupyterLab. If you'd like it to work in either make that clearer. Why is it in title?

Comment: I'm seeing issues like you suggest. [This person's experiences](https://github.com/3dmol/3Dmol.js/issues/635#issuecomment-1371207567) are consistent with yours. The thread has been closed. I'd suggest prematurely. It seems the developer now focuses on Google Colab much of the time. In fact, I wish they'd change the top banner at [the main pyMol3D page (seems is now branded '3Dmol.js')](https://github.com/3dmol/3Dmol.js/issues/635#issuecomment-1371207567) to not say 'Jupyter' because Google Colab differs significantly now. They branched off years ago and aren't equivalent now.

Comment: <continued> Places I had seen py3Dmol work before don't currently work. Which is consistent with your issues. I'm still looking around but wanted to let you know I wasn't having much luck either.

Comment: Yes, no luck with https://github.com/pwrose/mmtf-genomics that was dated to May 2022. I just see an empty space in the classic notebook interface (even at the Pangeo offering). There's clearly space set aside to show the viewer but nothing displays.

Comment: @Wayne Thank you so much for your input, as this issue had been driving me insane. In the discussion on github you linked people seem to be fine with py3dmol==2.0.0.post2 but I'm using this version and not getting it to work.
Are you using py3dmol yourself? Do you think I can do anything about this or should i abandon using py3dmol in the future?

You're maybe right and i should have put it in the title - though didn't have much success asking about py3dmol on this forum yet so I thought other topics would make more sense. Also I really thought this was about Jupyter and not py3dmol :(

Comment: I presently don't use py3dmol. I do know that it used to work. So I wouldn't suggest abandoning it yet. It may be an easy fix for the developer. I think though the developer needs to be aware of the issue. Since the focus of the one I linked to was Google Colab, I'm not sure it bing a more general problem with vanilla Jupyter is being caught. That's why I said I argue that the issue may have been closed too early. Don't worry about the title too much. I was just trying to advise that typically this isn't going to get the right person to help you. At this point, you'd probably get more ...

Comment: <continued> traction by pursuing one of two things: (1) Reach out to someone who uses it. The repo I linked to above at https://github.com/pwrose/mmtf-genomics that uses it is by Peter Rose. He's nice and he may be interested in why using py3dmol launched from his repo isn't working now. Or he may instantly be able to see something we are missing? Or know the right questions to ask the developer. (2) Work at the pymol3D repo. Look into more of the issue reports and see if a recent **unclosed** one matches better. Or post a new issue if not.

Comment: <continued> py3Dmol is very actively developed and I believe more people will become familiar with it as the AlphaFold 2 Colab offering uses it, see in [the Acknowledgments section there](https://github.com/sokrypton/ColabFold/tree/main#acknowledgments): "Also credit to David Koes for his awesome py3Dmol plugin, without whom these notebooks would be quite boring!" (My minor gripes are that I do though wish the branding was more consistent. Or the evolution of it was made more clear places. Plus, the documentation or repo README conspicuously link to https://3dmol.csb.pitt.edu/index.html !?!)

Comment: <continued> That last comment was to add more reason that I would not abandon it's use yet. Quite the opposite.